# How to reproject a point from one image to other image using homography matrix in opencv?

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision

I have two images I1 and I2 taken at a different perspective. I have computed homography matrix H using findHomography function in OpenCV. Now I need to reproject (i.e., to find the pixel coordinates) the center pixel p1(x,y) of image I1 over the image I2.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: http://ags.cs.uni-kl.de/fileadmin/inf_ags/3dcv-ws11-12/3DCV_WS11-12_lec04.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the slides. I have just computed H matrix from pair of points from two images. This function perspectiveTransform( src_points, dest_points, H) solved it.

Answer (score 2):

A homography is basically a linear mapping i.e. it can be performed by a simple multiplication with a 3x3-matrix. To introduce actual non-linear translation [Homogeneous coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates) are used (But this is a more tedious story).

Long story short, if you have OpenCV data types e.g. `Point2f` you can use the shipped [perspectiveTransform](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#perspectivetransform) to warp points perspectively.

```
std::vector<Point2f> src_points;
std::vector<Point2f> dest_points;
// ... add some points to src_points and get H e.g. from findHomography
perspectiveTransform( src_points, dest_points, H);
```

You'll find a more extensive example [here](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_homography/feature_homography.html).

Comment: Solved! Thanks a lot. This is what I was looking at.

Comment: You're welcome. If you are satisfied please accept and upvote my answer. Thank you.

Comment: Sure gfkri. Done it already, since i am new to stackoverflow my votes will appear once i earn min 15 reputations. pls upvote my question if its a valid one. Thanks.